# Error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime while attempting Invoke-WebRequest copied from chrome developer tools

Tags: powershell, rest, google-chrome

I am trying to debug an issue with our rest API from our website using the "Copy as powershell" option in the network tab of the chrome developer tools. The request does not work when I paste the command into powershell.

I am not sure what date it is talking about. Does it try to parse the "Expires" header or is it expecting a date somewhere else? Here is the command I am using as it was given to me from chrome.

```
$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$session.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/106.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("ApplicationGatewayAffinityCORS", "c00ac4926aa1674224fe8bf89fd800cc", "/", "example.com")))
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("ApplicationGatewayAffinity", "c00ac4926aa1674224fe8bf89fd800cc", "/", "example.com")))
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://example.com/api/v1/data" `
-WebSession $session `
-Headers @{
"Accept"="application/json, text/plain, */*"
  "Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
  "Accept-Language"="en-US,en;q=0.9"
  "Cache-Control"="no-cache"
  "Expires"="Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
  "If-Modified-Since"="0"
  "Pragma"="no-cache"
  "Referer"="https://example.com/"
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest"="empty"
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode"="cors"
  "Sec-Fetch-Site"="same-site"
  "X-Authentication"="ey...HZGcc0Q"
  "X-Correlation-Id"="7952caaa-ea81-47c1-aef9-79097ac8592e"
  "X-Request-Id"="0bd22d24-1b4c-407d-ba7c-38e0c7eb089f"
  "sec-ch-ua"="`"Chromium`";v=`"106`", `"Google Chrome`";v=`"106`", `"Not;A=Brand`";v=`"99`""
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile"="?0"
  "sec-ch-ua-platform"="`"Windows`""
}
```

Here is the error.

```
Invoke-WebRequest : String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://example.com ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Invoke-WebRequest], FormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.FormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

Comment: Maybe try removing that `"If-Modified-Since"="0"`.

Comment: Yes, not sure why chrome adds this but removing this header fixed it.